# Run same instance of terminal with build task in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a build.bat file for which I would like VS Code to run when I try and build my project. To do this in  VS Code you setup a task.json file and I've done so:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "${workspaceRoot}\\build.bat"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm having is each time I run the task it seems to generate a new terminal instance. Is there a way to have VS Code keep re-using the same terminal instance for its build tasks?

Comment: Does the https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior "panel": "dedicated" property work for you?

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it would be the property to set but not sure if it's actually working. The issue is within my build.bat file I have this line: `if not defined DevEnvDir ( call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" )` which should only be running the vcvars64.bat on the first build. When I execute my build.bat in a normal cmd terminal it works as expected. Though when runnin the task, the vcvars64.bat is run each and every time the task is executed.

Comment: nice question! never figured it out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :

```
  terminal.integrated.automationShell
```

Setting to set the shell that will be used for all automation in VS Code, which includes Tasks